# Dapper and "Operation could destabilize the runtime" when naming column 'Id'

Tags: .net, dapper

I use dapper in .NET 4.5 to ease querying my MS SQl database. The following works just fine:

**NO PROBLEMS:**

```
const string sql = @"
SELECT g.Name, g.Slug, g.CreatedDate, COUNT(r.Id) recipientCount
FROM Groups g
LEFT JOIN GroupRecipients r ON r.GroupId = g.Id
WHERE g.CustomerId = @CustomerId
GROUP BY g.Id, g.Name, g.Slug, g.CreatedDate

";
```

return _connection.Query(sql, new { CustomerId = customerId }).ToList();

**PROBLEM SELECTING 'Id' COLUMN - RAISES VerificationException**:

```
const string sql = @"
SELECT g.Id, g.Name, g.Slug, g.CreatedDate, COUNT(r.Id) recipientCount
FROM Groups g
LEFT JOIN GroupRecipients r ON r.GroupId = g.Id
WHERE g.CustomerId = @CustomerId
GROUP BY g.Id, g.Name, g.Slug, g.CreatedDate

";
return _connection.Query<GroupWithRecipientCount>(sql, new { CustomerId = customerId }).ToList();
```

The exception is thrown with the message **'Operation could destabilize the runtime.'**

Can anyone pinpoint what I may be doing wrong here? My **GroupWithRecipientCount** class looks like this:

```
public class GroupWithRecipientCount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Slug { get; private set; }
    public int RecipientCount { get; private set; }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

I removed this:

If I **rename the Id column** to something else than 'Id', everything works fine, i.e.

```
"SELECT g.Id SomeOtherName, g.Name, ..."
```

Looks like it also breaks if rename my class' Id field to SomeOtherName, so I guess the problem is related to mapping the Id field, but thats just a guess.

Comment: That error suggests *I* did something wrong, not you... taking a quick peek, but I might not be able to look properly just this moment

Comment: What is the exact type of `g.Id` in the database?

Comment: Uniqueidentifier, Not nullable.

Comment: I just realised that the type of the Id-field in C# was int. I changed this to Guid and then it works fine. A little misleading exception however :)

Comment: that's odd; trying it locally, I get "Error parsing column 0 (Id=86a53359-4fb8-4643-b9e0-6faf73479bc4 - Object)" - it could well be that the pending code already tidies this up plenty

Comment: Did you make a test including a join and count in the same way as my example?

Comment: I cut out the `join`, but the results from the SQL should have been identical (I set up a `@table` along that schema, with some invented data)

Comment: But I do not have the issue in queries where I do not join.

Comment: dapper doesn't see the join; it only sees the columns that come back

Comment: Thats weird. I will try to reproduce the problem with a reduced setup and get back to you.

Comment: When I run the exact same code from a console app, I get the same error as you. But when I run it in my MVC4 site, I get the other exception. It seems like it may be related to some security settings when hosting the MVC site.

Comment: For reference, I have these lines in the call stack:

- Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader) in c:\Dev\Dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:2126

- Deserialize0713505f-417b-4ddf-a58b-b8ae5a3f1a7f(IDataReader ) +584

- Dapper.<QueryInternal>d__d`1.MoveNext() in c:\Dev\Dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:827

- System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381

- System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got this exception when my model class had the wrong data type when mapping to a SQL field.  My model was an (wrongly) an int and the SQL statement was returning a string.  Double-check your data types if you get this cryptic error message.

Comment: yep, I was there too... the query was casting to char and my field on C# was an int. Changed to string and voila! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turned out some security issue I had choked the original exception and threw another exception instead.